# Props are not being passed into a React component from Meteor createContainer

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a really annoying issue and can't understand why it's happening. I have the following container:

```
export default SomeContainer = createContainer(( params ) => {

    const handle1 = Meteor.subscribe('SomePub');
    const isReady1 = handle1.ready();

    var someData = [];
    if( isReady1 ){
         someData = collections.SomeColl.find({}).fetch();
    }

    console.log(someData);

    return {
        someData: someData
    };

}, SomeComponent);
```

Here is the component:

```
export class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props);
    }
};
```

When I `console.log` the contents of `someData` from with the container, it contains some data. However, when I check for `someData` in the props of the component, it just shows `someData` as an empty array.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Can you post your console log?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your console log you should see the following:

1. logging from createContainer, showing someData is [] - because createContainer returns before the data has been fetched.
2. logging from SomeComponent.constructor, showing the same - this.props is [] (empty array)
3. logging from createContainer, showing data in someData  e.g.  [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] - your client now has the data in miniMongo, and has rerendered your component.

When your component receives the data from the server, it rerenders - rerunning createContainer, and the component's render method - but not the constructor.

If you move `console.log(this.props);` from your constructor to your render method, you will see it has received the data, and if you include it in the output, you will see it in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I realised that I needed to place the console.log in the componentWillReceiveProps function.